# How to send binary data by using sinatra-websocket?

Tags: javascript, ruby, websocket, sinatra

Sinatra-websocket has been installed on my Ubuntu system, and can be used to communicate with a JavaScript client in a browser using a text string.

Since it works for text, I want to transfer some binary data from a JavaScript client in the browser, which gets image data from a canvas, and send it to a Sinatra server using WebSocket. When the server gets data from the client, it just sends it back.
An error occurs when the server sends what it receives back. After trying to fix it for one night, I still don’t know how to conquer it.

Client side JavaScript code:

```
 var imgSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/img");

 var sendImageData = function(){
        var e = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var c = e.getContext('2d');
        var img = c.getImageData(0,0,200,200);
        var binary = new Uint8Array(img.data.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < img.data.length; i++) {
           binary[i] = img.data[i];
        }

        imgSocket.send(binary.buffer);
 };
```

Server side Ruby code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra-websocket'

set :bind, "0.0.0.0"
set :img_sockets, []

get '/img' do
  if !request.websocket?
    "hello"
  else
    request.websocket do |ws|
      ws.onopen do
        puts "img_socket opened"
        settings.img_sockets << ws
      end

      ws.onmessage do |msg|
        EM.next_tick {settings.img_sockets.each {|s| s.send(msg)}} #error occurs here
        #EM.next_tick {settings.img_sockets.each {|s| s.send("message from server")}} #if I just send back a text message, it’s OK.
      end

      ws.onclose do
        puts "img_socket closed"
        settings.img_sockets.delete(ws)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Error information from the server side:

```
Stopping ...
/home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/connection.rb:266:in `close_connection': eventmachine not initialized: evma_close_connection (RuntimeError)
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/connection.rb:266:in `close_connection'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:95:in `block in stop!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:95:in `each_value'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:95:in `stop!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/server.rb:190:in `stop!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1406:in `quit!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1431:in `ensure in run!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1431:in `run!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
Stopping ...
/home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/connection.rb:266:in `close_connection': eventmachine not initialized: evma_close_connection (RuntimeError)
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/em/connection.rb:266:in `close_connection'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:95:in `block in stop!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:95:in `each_value'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:95:in `stop!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/server.rb:190:in `stop!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1406:in `quit!'
    from /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1505:in `block in setup_traps'
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Looks like this issue has been submitted here: https://github.com/simulacre/sinatra-websocket/issues/10